# Order of product of two elements in an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $a, b \in G $ and let their order be $m$ and $n$ be respectively. Is it always true that order of $ab$ is $lcm(m,n)$?

What if $m$ and $n$ are coprime to each other?

Comment: Certainly the order of $ab$ need not be the lcm.  As a simple example, $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have the same order, but $a^{-1}a$ has very small order.

Answer (score 23):

When the group is finite and Abelian, you can show that if $d=\text{ord}(ab)$ where $m=\text{ord}(a)$ and $n=\text{ord}(b)$ then
$$d \mid \frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}=\text{lcm}(m,n)$$
and
$$\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)^2} \mid d.$$
${}{}{}{}{}$
In particular this means that if $m$ and $n$ are coprime the order is multiplicative.

Comment: So, if $m$ and $n$ are coprime to each other, the relation is true. right?

Comment: $m,n$ should be $mn$ but edits have to have at least 6 characters changes, so I cannot edit

Comment: could i have some reference for the fact;

Comment: @karhas For the proof of the first formula see [MathSE 1051177](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1051305/152568) and [Yashinski's notes](https://math.hawaii.edu/~allan/AdditionalGroupTheory.pdf), and for proof of the second [MathSE 2445367](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2445604/152568). Both and more are proved in [Jungnickel, On the Order of a Product in a Finite Abelian Group](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691399).

Answer (score 20):

You can prove that "anything" could happen for the order of a product.
In more precise words:

For any integers $m;n;r > 1$, there exists a finite group $G$ with elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ has order $m$, $b$ has order $n$, and $ab$ has order $r$.

For a beautiful proof, see Theorem 1.64 in http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf

Comment: $G$ is assumed to be abelian.

Comment: Best bounds for Abelian groups can be found in [Jungnickel, On the Order of a Product in a Finite Abelian Group](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691399). Anything can only happen within them, unlike in the general case.