# For an abelian group, is the order of a+b the lowest common multiple of orders a+b

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A true or false question, is there a counter example or short proof for this statement?

Let G be an abelian group. For all a, b ∈ G the order of a + b is the lowest
common multiple of the orders of a and b.

Comment: False, consider $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $1$ is of order 2 while $1+1=2$ is of order $1$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424097/order-of-products-of-elements-in-a-finite-abelian-group?rq=1). We need that $a+b\neq 0$. Note that $a\circ b=a+b$ for addition as composition.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

Take $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\operatorname{ord}(2)=2$ as $2+2=0$.

But $\operatorname{lcm}(2,2)=2$, and $\operatorname{ord}(0)\neq 2$

Comment: Just for information, this question comes straight from an online exam at the University of Warwick, which was taking place when the question was posted.