# Order of product of abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra

This a question from Algebra by Artin.
Let a,b be elements of an abelian group of orders m,n respectively. What can you say about the order of their product ab?

Here is my attempt:

$a^m=1=b^n$

$a^mb^n=1$

$b^n=a^{-m}$

$b^{n-1}=a^{-(m-1)}$
(Not sure if i can assume above step)

So:

$aa^{m-1}bb^{n-1}=aa^{m-1}a^{-(m-1)}b=1$

$ab=1$

So the order of the product $ab$ is $1$

Comment: No, this is not true. from $b^n=a^{-m}$ you can not conclude $b^{n-1}=a^{-(m-1)}$ because $a^{-(m-1)}=a^{-m+1}=b^{n+1}\ne b^{n-1}$ in general. I have a feeling the order should be the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Something went wrong:  The only element of order $1$ in any group is the identity.  So this is implying that the product of any two non-identity elements in any abelian group is the identity.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain showed where you made a mistake. The question is about the product $ab$ so consider $c=ab$ and look for $n$ such that $c^n=1$. The abelian character of the group will be very useful at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose

$$ord(a)=m\;,\;\;ord(b)=n\;,\;\;\text{gcd}\,(m,n)=d\implies xm+yn=d\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;m,n,d\in\Bbb N$$

Now, define $\;c:=ab\;$ :

$$c^{mn/d}\stackrel{\text{why?}}=a^{mn/d}\;b^{mn/d}=\left(a^m\right)^{n/d}\left(b^n\right)^{m/d}=1\cdot1=1$$

(Observe that $\;\frac nd\,,\,\,\frac md\in\Bbb Z\;$)

But of course

$$\frac{mn}d=\text{lcm}\,(m,n)\;\;,\;\;\;\text{and we're done}$$

Comment: I think you have only shown that the order of $c=ab$ divides $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$. This does not prove that they are equal.

Comment: I know @Jesko. In the most general case, the above is the most we can say about the order of $\;ab\;$. It isn't true that it **always** equals the lowest common multiple of the elements' orders.