# Trying to show $|ab|$ divides lcm$(|a|,|b|)$

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to solve this Putnam problem. The problem is "show that for a finite group with $n$ elements of order $p$, where $p$ is prime, either $n=0$ or $p\: \vert\: n+1$."

I'm trying to do this by showing we can create a subgroup of all elements such that $a^p=e$ (assuming $n\neq 0$, this group will have $n+1$ elements; all of our elements of order $p$ plus the identity). Then by Lagrange's Theorem, the order of an element divides the order of the group, so $p\:|\:n+1$.

I'm having trouble showing the closure of this subgroup though. I know that for a finite abelian group, $|ab|$ divides lcm$(|a|,|b|)$. If I can show this for a general group, then I can show that $|ab|=p$ because $p$ is prime. I'm having trouble doing this though. Anybody have any ideas? Or maybe I'm going about this problem completely wrong.

edit: never mind

Comment: Try looking at the set of *distinct* (cyclic) subgroups of order $p$.

Answer (score 1):

|ab| does not in general divide lcm(|a|,|b|).   See the earlier post, with a link to a nice proof.  [Order of product of two elements in a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67180/order-of-product-of-two-elements-in-a-group)

Comment: so there aren't any special circumstances when $|a|=|b|=p$ where $p$ is prime?

Comment: The statement of theorem is:  "For any integers $m;n; r > 1,$ there exists a finite group G with elements $a$ and $b$ such that $|a|=m, |b|=n,$ and $|ab|=r.$"    So i'ts  possible to construct a non-abelian group with elements $a,b$   of order $p$,  yet $|ab|$ not divisible by $p.$