# o(a)=m ,o (b) =n , ab=ba then o(ab)=lcm(m,n). What happens when b is the inverse of a?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group and let $a,b \in G$ s.t $O(a)=m$ and $O(b)=n$ and $ab=ba$. Then $O(ab)=lcm( m,n)$.

My attempt:
since $ab=ba$ then $HK=KH$

$ |HK|=O(H)O(K)/O(H \cup K)$

$l=(mn)/O(H \cap K)$
$\Longrightarrow O(H \cap K).
l=(mn)$
$ O(H \cap K) | gcd(m,n)$
$ \therefore mn=O(H \cap K).l \leq gcd(m,n).lcm (m,n)=mn$
$ \Longrightarrow O(H \cap K)=gcd(m,n)$ and $l=lcm(m,n)$ as this is the only possibility

What is wrong with this proof as if $b=a^{-1}$ then it doesnt work.

Comment: You are correct, the result itself doesn't work as $o(ab)=1\neq lcm(m,n)$.

Comment: There are other cases where the result isn't correct: let $a$ be an element of order $2m$ in $C_{2m}$ and let $b=a$.  Then $ab=ba=a^2$ and $O(ab)=O(a^2)=m\neq\mathrm{lcm}(2m, 2m)$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67180/order-of-product-of-two-elements-in-a-group) might help you.

Comment: $ |HK|=O(H)O(K)/O(H \cup K)$

$l=(mn)/O(H \cap K)$
$\Longrightarrow O(H \cap K).
l=(mn)$
$ O(H \cap K) | gcd(m,n)$
$ \therefore mn=O(H \cap K).l \leq gcd(m,n).lcm (m,n)=mn$
$ \Longrightarrow O(H \cap K)=gcd(m,n)$ and $l=lcm(m,n)$ as this is the only possibility

What is wrong with this proof as if $b=a^{-1}$ then it doesnt work.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Why does this happen when o(a)=o(b).

Comment: To sum up, "let $a,b \in G$ s.t $O(a)=m$ and $O(b)=n$ and $ab=ba$. Then $O(ab)=lcm( m,n)$" is wrong but "let $a,b \in G$ s.t $O(a)=m$ and $O(b)=n$ and $ab=ba$. Then $O(ab)$ divides $lcm( m,n)$" is true.

Comment: Psiible dublicate of  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67180/order-of-product-of-two-elements-in-a-group

Answer (score 4):

$o(a)$ is equal to $o(\langle a\rangle)=o(H).$

But, $o(ab)$ is not necessarily the order of $\langle a\rangle.\langle b\rangle=HK$.

You may track which argument is not valid in your proof.

The statement in the title is wrong. It should be

> If $o(a)=m$, $o(b)=n$ and if $ab=ba$ then $o(ab)$ **divides** $lcm(o(a),o(b))$.

Answer (score 0):

If o(a) = m, o(b) = n and

i) ab = ba

ii) < a > I < b > = {e}

```
   Then      O(ab) = l.c.m (m, n)
```

P. S. :   I = intersection