Determine an order of $ab$ with $|a|=6$, $|b|=10$ where $a,b \in G$, a finite abelian group.
(My solustion)
Let $k$ be $|ab|$, then $k$ must be one of divisors of $30$.
Suppose $k = 1$, then $ab = e$, 
$b = a^{-1}$, but $|a| \ne |b|$.
Hence $k \ne 1$.
Similarly, $2 , 3, 5, 6$ or $10$ cannot be $k$.
If $ k =15$, take $a =$ $e^{{{pi}\over{3}}i}$, $b =$ $e^{{{pi}\over{5}}i}$.
If $ k =30$, take $a =$ $-e^{{{pi}\over{3}}i}$, $b =$ $e^{{{pi}\over{5}}i}$.
Hence the number of order of $|ab|$ can be $15$ and $30$.

I thought the solution looks like incomplete so I asked this question.
I would appreciate if you let me know a better way to solve it. (or there is something wrong)

Consider the least common multiple.

You may want to check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67180/order-of-product-of-two-elements-in-an-abelian-group
